# Is there anyway to use Insert function using recursion without passing parameter? Is there any other way to make this program more efficient?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree, recursive-datastructures

Here I have coded the binary tree using recursion and is working perfectly fine but I want to know is there any way that I can use the insert function **without passing parameter for the root Node(i.e. address of the root node)**

Edit1: Reading the below comments I came to know in C there isn't another  way to use the insert function without passing the parameter of root node, so my next question is there any other way to make this program more efficient ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct Node *GetNewNode(int data)
{
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct Node *Insert(struct Node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = GetNewNode(data);
    }
    else if (data <= root->data)
    {
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right = Insert(root->right, data);
    }
    return root;
}


int main()
{
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    root = Insert(root, 15);
    root = Insert(root, 13);
    root = Insert(root, 14);
    root = Insert(root, 12);
    root = Insert(root, 11);
}
```

Comment: Is this C++ or C? If this is C++, you could make it a member function of `Node`. If it's not C++, I'd suggest removing the tag so you don't get unhelpful answers for another language.

Comment: If you don't pass the root, how would the program know under which root to add the data?

Comment: Since the `root` in `main()` is a static, simply access the same static.   Of course there are drawbacks to that, depending on your needs - for example, if you do that, then your program can only never have one tree structure (set of connected `Root` nodes).   That will prevent you, for example, from creating two such sets of connected `Root` nodes that don't refer to each other.

Comment: If this is a question about C this is impossible for one simple reason: there's no way to overload the function to only take a single parameter and you cannot set defaults for parameters. You may of course rename `Insert` to something else and create a new `Insert` function that starts at `root` and uses the old function as helper. In C++ you'd be better of wrapping the whole data structure in a class which could be named `Tree`.

Comment: @Jeffrey I made ```**root**``` global variable, so I am looking for the way to call it directly in the function ```Insert```

Comment: @UmangGupta that is a terrible design.

Comment: @Jeffrey Can you suggest better design?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don’t want to pass in a pointer to the root of the tree?

Comment: Parameters are basically the way to go. Don't use globals -- they make your program error-prone and harder to debug because the scope of a bug could involve complex interactions between multiple disparate components, functions aren't reusable or reentrant because they are dependent on some data named a certain way as a global. Functions should never access data outside of them. Tighter data scoping, more modularity, less sharing, weaker coupling, fewer dependencies, less mutability == more solid code.

Comment: @templatetypedef just want to learn/explore different methods.

Comment: @ggorlen Okay, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is rather unusual in that it sometimes mutates state and sometimes creates a new tree. It would be cleaner to simply always modify the input. This can be done as follows:

```c
typedef struct Node* Tree;

void insert(Tree* const root, int const data) {
    if (*root == NULL) {
        *root = GetNewNode(data);
    } else if (data <= (*root)->data) {
        insert(&(*root)->left, data);
    } else {
        insert(&(*root)->right, data);
    }
}
```

Now, we note that this is a tail-recursive procedure. Thus, we can trivially rewrite the procedure as follows:

```c
void insertIterative(Tree* root, int const data) {
    while(*root) {
        root = data <= (*root)->data ? &(*root)->left : &(*root)->right;
    }
    *root = GetNewNode(data);
}
```

This is a much more efficient function than your original one because your original function is needlessly non-tail recursive. If we want to replicate your original function's inputs and outputs, we can simply write

```c
Tree Insert(Tree root, int const data) {
    insertIterative(&root, data);
    return root;
}
```

As many have noted in the comments, if a function depends on an input like `root`, it is the best practice to pass the input in to the function.

Comment: The parameter `root` should be a double pointer.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `root` is a double pointer (root is of type `Tree*`, which is an alias for `Node**`). My last function was simply indicating that we could implement the function that OP wrote (with `root` not being a double pointer) using the double-pointer version.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. :)